# Misplaced tooltip in Site Analytics graph

Tags: bug, design, tooltips, site-analytics

The tooltips in the Posts graph on the [Site Analytics page](/site-analytics) are misplaced. Sometimes, they appear to be part of the next graph (see below) - the arrow indicates the point I was hovering over.

[image: Site Analytics Posts graph with misplaced tooltip]

This could be caused by the new responsive design; when I originally reported the bug, I checked two other sites (Ask Different and Chess) which didn't have the new design back then, and there the tooltips appeared reasonably close to the data point (the bottom right one in [this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KETz.png)).

Answer (score 3):

This is still the case today:

[image: a tooltip in the middle of the graph, far away from my cursor]
[image: a tooltip way off to the right side of the page]

The offset of the tooltip appears to depend on the width of the window. When my browser window is maximized, the tooltips are even further away. If my browser window is narrowed, there's very little horizontal offset. (This doesn't affect or explain the vertical offset being wildly off though.)