# Traffic and votes missing for recent days in site analytics

Tags: bug, traffic, site-analytics

**EDIT**: it's happening again today on Meta Stack Exchange; the last Traffic data point is from Monday, November 18th, more than two days ago. On Chess.SE, the last data point is November 20th, as expected.

There's something wrong with some of the information on the [site analytics pages](/help/privileges/site-analytics) across the network. It's November 6th, and the date selector on top of the page says the data is up to November 5th:

[image: Site Analytics date selector]

Yet on some sites like Meta Stack Exchange, Chess Stack Exchange and Board Games Stack Exchange, the latest data point for traffic is November 3rd:

[image: Traffic on Meta Stack Exchange]

The arrow indicates the data point I'm hovering over and the corresponding ([misplaced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313890/295232)) tooltip.

For votes, the latest data point is November 4th; posts are up to date.

On Ask Different, the situation is slightly different; new visits are up to date but the last data point for page views and visits is November 2nd:

[image: Traffic on Ask Different]

I *think* it used to be up-to-date in the past; the screenshot in [this old bug report of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/295232) was made on April 11th and shows data points (though with the wrong values) up to April 10th.

Comment: I can confirm this issue is also happening on Interpersonal Skills.

Comment: Hmmm, I see latest data on all those sites. I blame caching here; can you confirm whether you see recent data now?

Comment: Thanks, traffic has been restored. Votes still have one day missing.

Comment: @DeanWard 'Votes' is still ending at November 4th, just like yesterday. Could be caching, but then I'd recommend a shorter expiration time :)

Comment: @DeanWard it's happening again today on Meta Stack Exchange; the last Traffic data point is from Monday, November 18th, more than two days ago. On Chess.SE, the last data point is November 20th, as expected.