# Missing page views from site analytics since 30th of May

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, traffic, site-analytics

I was looking at the site analytics available to 25k users on Roleplaying Games (where I'm a moderator) and noticed that the page views data ends on the 30th of May:

[image]

The same data (total page views) also stops on the 30th in the diamond mod tools.

When downloading the data as a csv there simply aren't rows for the days after the 30th, presumably becuase one of the columns have missing data.

---

There's also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337649/681403) which appears highly related and not fully addressed, but the cases reported there are for much shorter time (not a week of missing data).

Comment: On this very site and on Stack Overflow I have no repro. But I'm checking //site-analytics as a 25K privileged user. Maybe the mod route is different.

Comment: No repro for mod analytics on Drones

Comment: Hmm.. It is now no longer happening on RPG.SE either, so unless something was done behind the scenes, it seems likely to be the same problem as the one linked. I'm not sure if it is getting worse (a week as opposed to a few days) or not. And if not solvable should it perhaps be noted somewhere related, say on `/help/privileges/site-analytics` which otherwise covers related quirks.